# Verb+ing as a verb beginning a sentence

Tags: verbs, writing-style, sentence-starts, present-participles

Is this good English?

> Falling into the ocean, the drop dies as a drop, but not as water.

Or should I say:

> When it falls into the ocean, the drop dies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a sentence with a verb in an *-ing* form is perfectly valid and acceptable. If properly used, it sounds dramatic and professional.

Example:

> Running through the crowd I didn't pay enough attention and didn't spot the robber.

As for what you propose - it sounds fine, but I'd omit the first comma, thus writing:

> Falling into the ocean the drop dies as a drop, but not as water.

Comment: I want to edit your answer to remove the 'Yes'.

Comment: @Sam: You safely could have, but I've done it myself now. Thanks for pointing out a way to improve my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely correct to use the latter, although both are technically correct according to 
english rules...

Comment: When has English become a common noun?